# configurations getByName not working in gradle when publishing POM file to Artifactory

Tags: android, build.gradle, artifactory

I'm using a publishing section in my build.gradle file for publishing an Android library to Artifactory:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    aar(MavenPublication) {
        groupId packageName
        version = libraryVersion
        artifactId project.getName()

        // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
        artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

        pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':smartcardsdk:generatePomFileForAarPublication'.
> Could not apply withXml() to generated POM
> Configuration with name '_releaseCompile' not found.
```

This was not a problem with Android v2.x. Problem started when I upgraded to Android Studio v3 (and I guess Gradle v3.0.0 as well).

I'm guessing that the configurations are no longer stored with the _releaseCompile name.

Does anyone know what the new "name" should be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just figured it out. You have to change it to:

```
"releaseCompileClasspath"
```

Comment: That worked! Many thanks for taking the time to figure it out.

Comment: I'm curious is it the right way to publish android library? I mean to walk through the dependencies manually. Isn't it a work for a publishing plugin?

Comment: @mdv Well, i would say that not everyone wants to publish their artifact bloated with dependencies, so maybe that's why it hasn't been built into the main Artifactory plugin. Or maybe there is some other way i'm not familiar with.